# showing that the range of an operator is not closed

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Consider the operator $A$: $l_2\rightarrow l_2$ defined by

$$A(\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots\}) = (\{ x_1,x_2/2,x_3/3,\ldots, \}) .$$

By a general theorem, this operator (apparently bounded and injective) is not bounded below so its range is not closed. My question is, can we find an explicit series $\{y_n = Ax_n\}$ such that $\{y_n \}$ converges to some $y$ which is not in the range of $A$?

Comment: Let $\{e_k\}$ denote the standard basis of $\ell ^2$. Consider $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n e_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $$y_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\,e_k=A\Big(\sum_{k=1}^ne_k\Big).$$ This sequence converges to $$y=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\,e_k.$$ But $y$ is not in the range of $A$, as this would require the non-existent element $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e_n$.